# Ext Js Grid, How to get the value of cell on keyup?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs-grid

I'm using Ext Js v6.2 Grid, In my application, I need to get the value of the cell on keyup Here my code, I've tried but it doesn't return the value,please correct my code if I'm wrong, I've searched in documentation and other stuff it doesn't help.please solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

**Update Code**

```
    Ext.define('MisCharge', {
                    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                    fields: [
                        {name: 'name', mapping: 'name'},
                        {name: 'age', mapping: 'age'},
                        {name: 'marks', mapping: 'marks'}
                    ]

                });
            }


// Store data
            var myData = [
                {name: "Container Cost"},
                {name: "Packaging Cost  "},
                {name: "Handling Charges "},
                {name: "Service Cost of Buyer "},
                {name: "Documentation"},
                {name: "Cntry of origin Cert."},
                {name: "Royalties"},
                {name: "Value of Proceeds"},
                {name: "Warranty Services"},
                {name: "Seller Obligation"},
                {name: "Other Charges"},
            ];
            // Creation of first grid store
            var gridStore1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                model: 'MisCharge',
                data: myData,
            });
            // Creation of first grid
            var gridStore = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                cls: 'custom-grid',
                id: 'gridId',
                store: gridStore1,
                stripeRows: true,
                width: '100%',
                collapsible: false,
                enableColumnMove: false,
                columnLines: true,
                sortableColumns: false,
                enableColumnHide: false,
                enableColumnResize: false,
                enableRowHeightSync: true,
                columns:
                        [{
                                header: "Charges",
                                dataIndex: 'name',
                                id: 'charge',
                                width: 200,
                                height: 20,
                                flex: 1

                            },
                            {
                           editor: {
                           xtype: 'textfield',
                           enableKeyEvents: true,
                           listeners: {
                           keyup: function (form, e) {
                           var sel_model = gridStore.getSelectionModel(); 
                           var record = sel_model.getSelection()[0];
                           alert(record);
                                        }
                                    }

                                },
                                header: "Rate%",
                                dataIndex: 'age',
                                flex: 1,
                                sortable: true,
                                height: 20,
                                hideable: false,
                            },
                            {
                                editor: {
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
//                                    selectOnFocus: true
                                },
                                header: "Amount()",
                                dataIndex: 'marks',
                                flex: 1,
                                height: 20,
                                sortable: true,
                            }],
                selType: 'cellmodel',
                plugins: [
                    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
                        clicksToEdit: 1
                    })]
            });
```

Comment: Where are you adding the listener?

Comment: This is not quite clear. A grid cannot have a `keyup` listener, unless in an editor field. Your code shows `form`, but a grid has no form.

Comment: Nevertheless, there is an obvious error in your code : `gridStore` is not defined. If your code sits inside a closure, then it is an unusual way to write extjs code. In this case please show the whole function with its surroundings.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer full code updated. thanks.

Comment: @AlexandreN. adding listener to editor field, full code shown. thanks.

Comment: Is this really your code?! The way you name and use the variables `gridStore` and `gridStore1` makes that it is invalid JavaScript : you cannot use a variable inside its own declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the event by referencing the `el` element.

```
editor: {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        enableKeyEvents: true,
        listeners: {
            keyup: {
                element: 'el',
                fn: function (a, b) {
                    var record = gridStore.getSelectionModel().selected.items[0].data
                    alert(record);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried but Its returning only [object Object], not the value.

Comment: So try something like `document.getElementById(b.id).value`, In your case you used `keyup: function (form, e)`, then should stay `document.getElementById(e.id).value`

Comment: Okay, remember to accept the solution so that other people who go through this problem can solve it as well. And flag +1 feedback if you liked it!